# Python - Using an operator to assign a file name when using a class

Tags: python, class, operators

I am a somewhat Python/programing newbie, and I am attempting to use a python class for the first time.

In this code I am trying to create a script to backup some files. I have 6 files in total that I want to back up regularly with this script so I thought that I would try and use the python Class to save me writing things out 6 times, and also to get practice using Classes.

In my code below I have things set up for just creating 1 instance of a class for now to test things. However, I have hit a snag. I can't seem to use the operator to assign the original filename and the back-up filename.

Is it not possible to use the operator for a filename when opening a file? Or am I doing things wrong.

```
class Back_up(object):
    def __init__(self, file_name, back_up_file):
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.back_up_file = back_up_file
        print "I %s and me %s" % (self.file_name, self.back_up_file)

        with open('%s.txt', 'r') as f, open('{}.txt', 'w') as f2 % (self.file_name, self.back_up_file):
            f_read = read(f)
            f2.write(f_read)

first_back_up = Back_up("syn1_ready", "syn1_backup")
```

Also, line #7 is really long, any tips on how to shorten it are appreciated.

Thanks
Darren

Comment: As a side note, there's really no reason to use a class here. A class that has no methods, no behavior, except its `__init__` constructor is just a confusing and verbose way to write a function. Unless you actually have some use for that `first_back_up` object later, that you haven't shown us?

Comment: As @steveha shows in his answer, if the code looks complicated in Python, you are probably doing it wrong (especially as a newbie). There are no awards for using the fewest lines of code in Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want your files backed up, may I suggest using `shutil.copy()`?

As for your program:

If you want to substitute in a string to build a filename, you can do it.  But your code doesn't do it.

You have this:

```
with open('%s.txt', 'r') as f, open('{}.txt', 'w') as f2 % (self.file_name, self.back_up_file):
```

Try this instead:

```
src = "%s.txt" % self.file_name
dest = "{}.txt".format(self.back_up_file)
with open(src, "rb") as f, open(dest, "wb") as f2:
    # copying code goes here
```

The `%` operator operates on a string.  The `.format()` method call is a method on a string.  Either way, you need to do the operation with the string; you can't have two `with` statements and then try to use these operators at the end of the `with` statements line.

You don't have to use explicit temp variables like I show here, but it's a good way to make the code easy to read, while greatly shortening the length of the `with` statements line.

Your code to copy the files will read all the file data into memory at one time.  That will be fine for a small file.  For a large file, you should use a loop that calls `.read(CHUNK_SIZE)` where `CHUNK_SIZE` is a maximum amount to read in a single chunk.  That way if you ever back up a really large file on a computer with limited memory, it will simply work rather than filling the computer's memory and making the computer start swapping to disk.

Comment: Nice explanation. The only thing you didn't mention is that `%s` placeholders only work with the `%` operator, and `{}` placeholders only work with the `format` method, and you can't mix them up. (That's pretty obviously implied by your code, but I'm not 100% sure a novice will pick it up.)

Comment: That was my confusion, I edited the code to replace `{}` with the now second instance of '%s', because that was how it was supposed to be originally. I am changing back to reflect the fact that steveha answered before my edit.

Comment: @steveha - thanks :-) I was not aware of shutil.copy(), it certainly makes everything simple, so I will go with that.

Comment: @steveha - also the files I am backing up are presently between 1 and 2.6mb and are growing every week

Comment: @Darren: Depending on a zillion different things about your configuration, the optimal CHUNK_SIZE can be anywhere from 2KB to 8MB. Copying a 2.6MB file all at once will be good enough. Still, better to let `shutil` figure out the hard stuff for you than to try to do it yourself, right?

Answer (score 2):

Try simplicity :)

Your line 7 is not going to parse. Split it using intermediate variables:

```
source_fname = "%s.txt" % self.file_name
target_fname = "%s.txt" % self.back_up_file
with open(source_fname) as source, open(target_fname) as target:
  # do your thing
```

Also, try hard avoiding inconsistent and overly generic attribute names, like `file_name`, when you have *two* files to operate on.

Your copy routine is not going to be very efficient, too. It tries to read the entire file into memory, then write it. If I were you I'd call `rsync` or something similar via `popen()` and feed it with proper list of files to operate on. Most probably I'd use `bash` for that, though Python may be fine, too.

Comment: Reading a whole file at a time will be plenty efficient except for very large files. Meanwhile, using `rsync` for a single file is not going to out-perform `cp`, so why make it more complicated? Also, why would you ever use `popen` instead of `subprocess`? And finally, Python's `shutil` functions are about as efficient as separate command-line tools, and a lot easier to use from Python.

Comment: I don't know how large are your files, how are they situated, etc. For instance, if source and destination are on different disks, especially network-mounted (makes sense when backing up) you can speed things up by doing reads and writes in parallel. I suspect `rsync` may be better at that, but `cp` would be "something similar" I mentioned. Yes, `subprocess` or `shutil` is superior; I just use them so rarely I forgot!

Comment: Neither cp nor rsync nor Python's shutil will automatically parallelize copying a file. And I think it would actually _hurt_ for slow network drives if you tried to do that. A useful way to parallelize would be at a higher level—run two copies at the same time. (In bash, just `cp src1 dst1 &` `cp src2 dst2 &` and wait for the two jobs; in Python; use a `multiprocessing.Pool` or `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` and submit `shutil.copy` jobs.)

Comment: @abarnert: I still suppose that writing a previous block while reading a next block would speed things up; this is usually done by having separate write and read buffers. This is sort of off-topic here, though, it seems: using a competently made copy program would be enough of an improvement.

Comment: You can only interleave your read and write like that if you use either async APIs (like `aio_read` on POSIX), or threads, and I guarantee you that neither `cp` nor `rsync` does. The reason is that you don't need to; the OS buffers writes for you, so you can pretend to be completely synchronous and get the benefits of interleaving.